# Which 'do' is an auxiliary verb in 'How do you do?'

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I always find it a bit difficult finding auxiliary verbs. How do they differ from the ordinary verbs?

> How do you do?

Are these both do's are auxiliary? Or general? Or both?

Is there any way to find an auxiliary verb in a sentence? How do I differentiate it with a general verb in the same sentence? Any easy trick?

Comment: The greeting *"How do you do?"* is a "frozen form". Do *not* attempt to understand "how it works" hoping to use this information to understand contemporary English, because it simply won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a "trick", i'd say, use the third person singular. The *auxiliary* verb will change:

> How do you do?
>   How **does** he do?

Also, the auxiliary verb cannot be replaced by another verb. The general one can, in order to change the meaning of the sentence:

> How do you do?
>   How do you swim?
>   How do you drive?

The first *do* I cannot replace like that:

> How do you do?
>   *How swim you do?
>   *How drive you do?

Comment: *I do not do anything when I'm nervous* - The first *do* is auxiliary...isn't it?

Comment: @oerkelens This is great advice but what's _ecan_? `The general on ecan...`

Comment: @MaulikV: yups, try "I do not **swim** when I'm nervous" or "He **does** not do anything when he's nervous".

Comment: @Helix: If you have any experience with the military you should know that a general on ecan can be incredibly dangerous. That substance is not to be given to generals, especially not general Motors, general Failure and general Electric. Also, I have an _eager-space_ keyboard. It works just like any other keyboard, but it tends to send out spaces just _one_ character too soon sometimes. It's still better than the alternative, the _lazy-space_ keyboard. Thatc anc ausee evenm orep roblems.